# jquery update dynamically added dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a jquery function that updates some input boxes on select of a dropdown option. I also dynamically add as many selects as I want using an addRow function with the same id as the first select. However, the jquery function is not triggered for the new selects. Below is my jquery for updating the input boxes:

```
$('#menusName').on("change",function ()
{
 var menId = $(this).val(); 

$.ajax
({
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/MainController/menuDetails",
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  data: "name="+menId,
  dataType: "json",

  success:(function(data) 
  {
    $('#makes').val(data[0]);
    $('#type').val(data[1]);
  })
})});
```

And also the addRow function:

```
function addRow(tableID)
{
        var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount=table.rows.length;
        var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount=table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
        {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            var oldId = table.rows[0].cells[i].childNodes[1].text;
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

            switch(newcell.childNodes[i])
            {
                case"#text":
                  newcell.childNodes[i].value="";
                  break;
                case"#checkbox":
                  newcell.childNodes[i].checked=false;
                  break;
                case"#select-one":
                  newcell.childNodes[i].selectedIndex=0;
                  break;
            }


        }
  }
```

And my HTML code below:

```
<table id="recipes" class="table">
        <a href="#" onclick="addRow('recipes');" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Another Recipe
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRow('recipes');" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </a>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="menusName" id="menusName" required>
                    <option>Choose a Menu</option>
                    <?php if($menus != null){
                        foreach($menus as $r){ ?>
                        <option><?php echo $r->menuName;?></option>
                    <?php }}?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Makes: <input readonly name="makes" id="makes" type="text" required/></td>
            <td>Cake Type: <input readonly name="type" id="type" type="text" required/></td>
            <td>Multiply Recipe by: <input name="mulRecipe" id="mulRecipe" type="text" required/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the  `$( document ).ready()` function :

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   /* your code  */
 });
```